# Cannot enqueue items to BlockingCollection used in abstract class

Tags: c#, multithreading, abstract-class, producer-consumer

As the title suggests I utilize an abstract class to create a reusable base class for adding and removing items with a BlockingCollection. I use the producer / consumer pattern to enqueue and dequeue items, the abstract class is generic so I can specify an object for the queue.

My issue occurs when I call the base classes Enqueue and Dequeue methods, they seem to be referencing a different instance of the queue, ie when I call dequeue there are no items on the queue and the enqueues TryAdd() returns true. However when I directly call Add or Take on the queue instance it works fine.

Can anyone tell me why the bases classes Enqueue and Dequeue methods do not work as I expect, I have tried looking up several uses of BlockingCollections and cannot see why.

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var processor = new Processor(1,4);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Abstract Base class

```
public abstract class BaseProcessor<T>: IDisposable
{
    protected BlockingCollection<T> _queue;
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
    private int _producers;
    private int _consumers;
    private List<Task> _tasks;

    public BaseProcessor(int producers, int consumers)
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<T>();
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _producers = producers;
        _consumers = consumers;
        _tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    protected void Setup()
    {
        Parallel.For(0, _producers, i =>
            _tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Produce(_tokenSource.Token), _tokenSource.Token)
            .ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} stopped", task.Id);
            }))
         );

        Parallel.For(0, _producers, i =>
            _tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consume(_tokenSource.Token), _tokenSource.Token)
            .ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} stopped", task.Id);
            }))
         );
    }

    protected abstract void Produce(CancellationToken token);
    protected abstract void Consume(CancellationToken token);

    protected void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = _queue.TryAdd(item, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not add item to queue: {0}", ex);
        }
    }

    protected void Enqueue(List<T> items)
    {
        items.ForEach(o => Enqueue(o));
    }

    protected T Dequeue()
    {
        try
        {
            T item;
            while (_queue.TryTake(out item, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))) ;
            return item;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not remove item to queue: {0}", ex);
            return default(T);
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Cancel all tokens
        _tokenSource.Cancel();

        // Wait for all tasks complete
        Task.WaitAll(_tasks.ToArray());

        _queue.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Abstract class implementation

```
public class Processor: BaseProcessor<QueueItem>
{

    private int _counter;

    public Processor(int producers, int consumers): base(producers, consumers)
    {
        _counter = 0;

        Setup();
    }

    protected override void Produce(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            var queueItem = new QueueItem()
            {
                Id = _counter,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now
            };

            //Enqueue(queueItem);
            _queue.Add(queueItem);

            Console.WriteLine("Enqueued: {0}", _counter);
            _counter++;

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    protected override void Consume(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var item = Dequeue();
            //var item = _queue.Take();
            Console.WriteLine("Dequeued: {0}", item.Id);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your `BaseProcessor<T>` class is an attempt to re-invent the [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) component of the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. I suggest to use the built-in class instead of your own, because it is simpler, it has more features, it supports both sync and async workloads, and it handles better the case of failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered the reason, its my implementation of some code taken from this link I was using. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3090215/how-to-work-with-blockingcollection-in-c.html

The while (_queue.TryTake(out item, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))); is dumping all the items from the queue, it is running until the queue is in fact empty. From the tutorial I presumed it was running whilst there was something to try and take.

Blind copy and paste issue on my behalf